# How to build a controller using ViewModel

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 tables in the ASP.NET MVC application:

- People (id, name, last_name)
- Computers (id, name, type, serial number)
- Office (person_id, computer_id, notes)

I need to display information in `Home/Index.cshtml`, which persons do not have a computer assigned.

I don't know how I should construct a controller using for example ViewModel.

Query

```
select * 
from Person d 
where not exists(select * from Office e where e.IdPerson = d.Id);
```

The query returns people who do not have an assigned computer.

Offices controller:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Offices.Models;

namespace Offices.Controllers
{
    public class OfficesController : Controller
    {
        private OfficesContainer db = new OfficesContainer();

        // GET: Offices
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.OfficeSet.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What information you want to display? I mean, do you want to display only name of person or also the lastname and other columns?

Comment: Exactly first and last name.

Comment: @Kris, do you want to use SQL query rather than entity framework?  (I can see you are using entity context on controller)

Comment: The application is in c # asp.net MVC. I need to install the Entity component. Any solution will be good

Answer (score 0):

```
var person= persons.where(s=> !Offices.where(es=> es.IdPerson=s.Id).Any());
```

Comment: How do I understand this is the Home controller code?

Comment: I receive a message: The Persons element does not contain a definition of "where".

Comment: can you upload  your project in Github and share to me?

Comment: To be honest I have never used Github :)

Comment: I want to help you Kris, but I think I can only help with code

Comment: Please share the context file